# Can I fly with an expired passport within Spain?

Tags: air-travel, passports, paperwork, spain, expired

I am a Spanish resident (with Spanish nationality) and I want to travel from one city to another in Spain by flight. I have lost my identity document (DNI). I do have a copy of a valid DNI, but its not the actual physical one, just a printed copy. I have a passport that expired at the beginning of 2022, is it possible to travel with it even so?

I have found some web pages that inform that you can flight if the passport is [expired within 5 years](https://administracion.gob.es/pag_Home/en/Tu-espacio-europeo/derechos-obligaciones/ciudadanos/viajes/documentos/pasaportes-caducados.html) while others say you clearly need a in-force one (not expired).

I went to [Air Europa](https://www.aireuropa.com/uk/en/aea/travel-information/documentation/general-documentation.html) and I see:

[image: screenshot of text]

Domestic flights

- National ID or Passport **(can be expired)**
- Driving licence issued in Spain

This is not what is quoted in an answer below. What are the actual rules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For domestic flights, airlines may set their own ID policy. Air Europa's [is here](https://www.aireuropa.com/uk/en/aea/travel-information/documentation/general-documentation.html). For third country nationals, they state one of the following documents is required:

> - Valid, non-expired passport or travel document
> - Valid residence permit from Spain or a Schengen Country
> - Driving licence (1)
> - Visa according to nationality.

> (1) A driving licence is only valid for domestic flights within the country issuing the document.

For Spanish nationals, they state the following documents are permitted:

> - Valid ID or Passport (can be expired)
> - Valid residence permit from Spain or a Schengen Country
> - Driving licence (1)

Since you have an expired Spanish passport I believe you will be permitted to fly.